# What is a $L^2$ Cauchy Sequence?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I am trying to understand the $L^2$ lemma, which I came across while studying convergence of series.

The $L^2$ Lemma I am referring to is as follows.

Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots$ be i.i.d. random variables with partial sums $S_n$. Then,

$\sum ^ \infty _ {n=1} Var (X_n) < \infty \iff \sum ^ \infty _ {n=1} (X_n - E(X_n))$ converges in L^2

However, after doing much googling, I am unable to find much information online regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

A Cauchy sequence is a sequence of points $\{ x_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $\forall \varepsilon > 0$ there is $M>0$ such that

$$
\| x_n - x_m \| < \varepsilon \quad \forall m,n > M.
$$

Intuitively, a Cauchy sequence is a collection of points that eventually gets close to (and stays close to) itself.  In the case of $L^2$, it is a complete space, which means that all Cauchy sequences have a limit in the space.  In the above, the norm would be the $L^2$ norm.  Cauchy sequences can be defined for other spaces based on their norm, and are often used to define a complete space, i.e. a space is complete if every Cauchy sequence in the space has a limit in the space.

Edit: to help clarify, what is the $L^2$ lemma you are referring to?

Comment: I have updated the question details with the lemma

Comment: @kengchi okay, so the term on the left can be written as $\sum_n E[(X_n - E(X_n))^2]$, from which we can factor out the expectation to get $E[\sum_n (X_n - E(X_n))^2]$.  Can you see where to go from here?